# String to String mapping using Spring?

Tags: java, string, spring, spring-mvc

From external system I receive String representation of some abbreviations and I have to make transformation(conversion) to another String for example:

```
"O" -> Open
"C" -> Closed
"E" -> Exit
```

For Object to Object conversion I was using Spring Custom COnverter

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
public class Converter<Source, Target> implements Converter<Source, Target>
 public final Target convert(@Nonnull Source source) {
 ...
 }
```

But I can't create String to String converter. I do not want to use external mapping library only Spring capabilities. But I can't do this. The simplest thing that I can do is switch

```
String input = "O";
String result = null;
switch(input){
 case "O": result ="Open"
 break;
case "C": result ="Close"
 break;
....
```

In matter of fact I have to do over 100 mapings. Can Spring  offer better solution?

Comment: Is this mapping fixed?

Comment: Yes. All mappings are fixed and we know for them.

Comment: Did you consider using a static HashMap instead of switch case?

Comment: It's interesting I have not thought about it

Answer (score 4):

When you don't have any logic to execute in switch-case, you can use a static `HashMap<String,String>`

```
  static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
  static
  {
      map.put("O","Open");
      map.put("C","Close");
      .....................

  }
```

Instead of switch-case just use

```
     map.get(input);
```

If you are suing Java 8, you can even use

```
    map.getOrDefault(input,"");
```

Comment: It might be clever to declare the map _not_ inside the static initializer block.

Comment: @Tom you mean to just remove static or declare the map outside static?

Comment: Move the line `HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();` outside of the static block. Currently your `map` is bound to that block and when the execution of that block is finished, then this map will be removed.

Comment: @Tom oh yeah! I missed that. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget that keyword `static` in front of the variable ;).

Comment: @Tom I missed that too :P, but this would not happen when I write code because my IDE is intelligent (even though I am not) :P